# Dynamic gridview without using datasource

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have one gridview and two buttons, add rows and add cols whenever i click on add row button it should add one row in grid and whenever i click on add cols button than it should add column in grid dynamically like that it should happen if i clicked on second time on add row button it should add another row.

Comment: show some code what you tried??

Answer (score 0):

As you don't posted your code, I guess you want this,
Put the below code in `onClick();` event of the Column add button.

```
    BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
    bfield.HeaderText = "Name";
    bfield.DataField = "Name";
    GridView1.Columns.Add(bfield);
```

It will add a column in your gridview
Now for binding the data

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[1] { new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)};

dt.Rows.Add("John Hammond");

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Hope it will help you..

Comment: Thanks for giving me ans but this code will generate only one row and one column but i want each and every button click i want more row and columns

Comment: Run this code on the OnClick() event of your button,So whenever you click that Add button It will add a new column, Rest you can customize that code according to your need.